# Does the category with one sheaf contain enough injectives?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It's well known that the category of abelian sheaves has enough injectives. Does this include the case where the category is just one abelian sheaf? How can one prove this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: If your category of sheaves is additive, this single object must be the zero object and the answer should be clear.